# How to setup intelephense with neovim + lua?

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp

I have 2 neovims, one with coc, and another with lua.
In neovim with coc, intelephense works.

I am working with wordpress, and i need intelephense.

Nvim coc setup.
plugins.vim

```
Plug 'yaegassy/coc-intelephense', {'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'}
```

coc-settings.json

```
  "intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
    "/home/serii/Sites/wordpress",
    "/home/serii/Sites/advanced-custom-fields-pro",
    "/home/serii/Sites/woocommerce"
  ],
```

But for lua config i just use intelephense in lsp installer.

```
  -- LSP
  use {
    "williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer",
    {
      "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
      config = function()
        require("nvim-lsp-installer").setup {
          ensure_installed = { "cssls", "sumneko_lua" }, -- ensure these servers are always installed
          automatic_installation = true, -- automatically detect which servers to install (based on which servers are set up via lspconfig)
          ui = {
            icons = {
              server_installed = "✓",
              server_pending = "➜",
              server_uninstalled = "✗"
            }
          }
        }
        --              local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
        --             lspconfig.sumneko_lua.setup {}
        --             
        -- Add additional capabilities supported by nvim-cmp
        local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
        capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionItem.snippetSupport = true
        capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').update_capabilities(capabilities)
        -- Mappings.
        -- See `:help vim.diagnostic.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
        local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<space>dg', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()<CR>', opts)
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '[d', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>', opts)
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', ']d', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_next()<CR>', opts)
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<space>l', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR>', opts)

        -- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
        -- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
        local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
          -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

          -- Mappings.
          -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gD', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gd', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'K', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gi', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<C-k>', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>wa', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>wr', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>wl', '<cmd>lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>D', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.type_definition()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>rn', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>ca', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gr', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>', opts)
          vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<M-l>', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()<CR>', opts)
        end

        -- Use a loop to conveniently call 'setup' on multiple servers and
        -- map buffer local keybindings when the language server attaches
        local servers = { 'tsserver', 'sumneko_lua', 'cssls', 'emmet_ls', 'intelephense' }
        for _, lsp in pairs(servers) do
          require('lspconfig')[lsp].setup {
            on_attach = on_attach,
            capabilities = capabilities,
          }
        end
      end
    }
  }
```

And i don't know how to config directories for wordpress files path.

Here i founded intelephense config https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/intelephense.lua

I created already a file intelephense.lua and included in init.lua.
But it is not working.

The settings are green.

[image: lua code]

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You say you have ``coc``, did you try the vim command: ``:CocInstall @yaegassy/coc-intelephense``?

Comment: You don't understand.
I have 2 neovims, one with coc, and another with lua. 

In neovim with coc intelephense work, but in neovim with lua, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i done.
I saw how is setting ls_emmet and setup intelephese.
Result.

intelephense.lua

```
local lspconfig = require 'lspconfig'
local configs = require 'lspconfig.configs'

local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionItem.snippetSupport = true

if not configs.intelephense then
  configs.intelephense = {
    default_config = {
      cmd = { 'intelephense', '--stdio' };
      filetypes = { 'php' };
      root_dir = function(fname)
        return vim.loop.cwd()
      end;
      settings = {
        intelephense = {
          files = {
            maxSize = 1000000;
          };
          environment = {
            includePaths = {
              "/home/serii/Sites/wordpress",
              "/home/serii/Sites/advanced-custom-fields-pro",
              "/home/serii/Sites/woocommerce"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
end

lspconfig.intelephense.setup { capabilities = capabilities }
```

Comment: There's a long code block here without much explanation of what is going on. Perhaps some explanation would help future readers? You can [edit] to expand your thoughts.